# How can I include private modules when generating documentation via Cargo?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'm currently working on a project with Rust and Cargo. It works well, but I encounter a little issue: for code reuse, most of my project is inside a lib crate. In this crate, a lot of things is private. So when I do `cargo doc`, I just have documentation for public, exported stuff... which is actually great, because it's easy to see what is exported and what is not.

But I have to admit: I miss a complete documentation of the whole project, for development purpose...

Comment: The [currently accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39374515/155423) is not the best solution now. Consider accepting a different answer with a more up-to-date solution.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

## [Rust 1.41](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/RELEASES.md#version-1410-2020-01-30)

Documentation for binaries includes private items from the binary crate by default.

## [Rust 1.29](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/RELEASES.md#version-1290-2018-09-13)

You can now use `cargo doc --document-private-items`

## Previous versions

You may not be able to do it with Cargo today, there is a workaround if you use rustdoc directly.

Run `cargo doc -v` and make a note of the rustdoc command it runs:

```
$ cargo doc -v
   Compiling docz v0.0.1 (file:///private/tmp/docz)
     Running `rustdoc src/lib.rs -o /private/tmp/docz/target/doc --crate-name docz -L dependency=/private/tmp/docz/target/debug -L dependency=/private/tmp/docz/target/debug/deps`
```

Then, add `--no-defaults --passes strip-hidden --passes collapse-docs --passes unindent-comments` to the command:

```
rustdoc src/lib.rs -o /private/tmp/docz/target/doc --crate-name docz \
    -L dependency=/private/tmp/docz/target/debug \
    -L dependency=/private/tmp/docz/target/debug/deps \
    --no-defaults \
    --passes strip-hidden --passes collapse-docs --passes unindent-comments
```

Comment: If you don't want to show re-exports, you will want to add `--passes strip-priv-imports` too.

Answer (score 14):

Use cargo to document private items:

```
cargo doc --document-private-items
```

Comment: You can also add a `.cargo/config` file to you project if you want it to be default: `[build] rustdocflags = ["--document-private-items"]`

Answer (score 8):

This can be done by passing arguments to rustdoc, after `--`, eg.

```
cargo rustdoc -- \
    --no-defaults \
    --passes strip-hidden \
    --passes collapse-docs \
    --passes unindent-comments \
    --passes strip-priv-imports
```

Based on @Shepmaster's answer, no need for manual copy-pasting.

Comment: `warning: the 'no-defaults' flag is considered deprecated`. Same for `passes`. The warnings recommend `--document-private-items`

Answer (score 8):

This is now simpler, just use:

```
cargo rustdoc -- --document-private-items
```

Comment: `rustdoc` requires running against an actual package, so it won't work with [a virtual manifest](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html#the-workspace-section). It's better to use `cargo doc --document-private-items`, which works with virtual manifests too.