# Correctly generating Rustdocs

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'm probably missing something incredibly obvious, but I'm having trouble generating documentation for my code. I'm reading [this](https://facility9.com/2016/05/writing-documentation-in-rust/) tutorial and from what I understand, I can simply do something like

```
/// this is a doc comment
pub fn something() {

}
```

and run `cargo doc --no-deps --open` to get my crate's html page. However, my `index.html` is just showing the crate name and nothing else.

I have the following structure:

```
src/
  | main.rs
  | random_file.rs
  | drivers/
    | mod.rs 
    | foo.rs 
    | dummy.rs
```

and in my `foo.rs` I have

```
/// in foo doc
pub fn bar() {

}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Try making the function public for a quick fix, if you really want it private, have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378113/how-can-i-include-private-modules-when-generating-documentation-via-cargo

Comment: @Prime_Aqasix apologies, the function is public

Comment: Does `main.rs` declare `mod drivers` public? does drivers/mod.rs declare `mod foo` public?

Comment: D'oh! That's it!