# Cargo doc does not generate documentation for private items in a project that is both a library and binary

Tags: rust, rustdoc

When I run `cargo doc`, it does not seem to generate documentation for the library in my project. I am using the latest version of Rust as answered by this post: [How can I include private modules when generating documentation via Cargo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378113/how-can-i-include-private-modules-when-generating-documentation-via-cargo)

This is my structure:

```
- services/
    - mod.rs
    - my_service.rs
- lib.rs
- main.rs
```

`main.rs` contains just the "main" function to start up:

```rust
use test_doc::Core;

fn main() {
    Core::start();
}
```

`lib.rs` contains the actual logic:

```rust
mod services;

/// Core process
pub struct Core;

impl Core {
    pub fn start() -> ! {
        loop {
            // do stuff here    
        }
    }
}
```

Then `my_service.rs` contains some more logic:

```rust
/// My service should do stuff
pub struct MyService;

impl MyService {
    /// This function actually does stuff
    pub fn do_stuff(&self) -> &'static str {
        "doing stuff"
    }
}
```

`mod.rs` inside `my_service` folder simply serves as an entry point:

```rust
pub mod my_service;
```

This code compiles and executes successfully, but I'm not sure why the docs are not generated properly.

Here is a screenshot of the docs that are generated when I run `cargo doc --open`:
[image]

I can't find `MyService` documented anywhere... (clicking "Structs" link just jumps to an anchor point on the main page)

Comment: Reread the post you linked: *Documentation **for binaries** includes private items from the binary crate by default.*. You are looking at the documentation for a library. What happens when you `cargo doc --document-private-items`?

Comment: Tried that, same thing. As I understood, it the linked posts is saying this should be default behaviour by Rust 1.41

Comment: Yes, if you document a **binary** (main.rs). You are looking at the documentation for a **library** (lib.rs).

Comment: I'm a little confused. My project contains both `main.rs`, and `lib.rs`. So is it a library or a binary? Or both?

Comment: Incidentally, I tried `cargo doc --lib --open`, to generate the documentation for the library, it still doesn't work

Comment: `cargo doc --lib --open --document-private-items`

Comment: It's both, but `cargo doc` evidently defaults to looking at the library.

Comment: Aha! Thanks, that command works.

Comment: From `cargo doc --help`, you can also use `cargo doc --bins` to document the binary (thus including private items).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A much smaller example:

**src/main.rs**

```
//! THE BINARY

fn main() {}
```

**src/lib.rs**

```
//! THE LIBRARY

/// You can't see me
fn private() {}
```

When I run `cargo doc`, I see that Rust 1.55 on macOS generates the documentation *for the library*. As stated in [How can I include private modules when generating documentation via Cargo?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29378113/155423), when documenting a library, private items are not included. You need to pass the `--document-private-items` flag to see them.

If you wish to document *the binary*, you'll need to pass the `--bin` or `--bins` flag. If you wish to document *the library*, you'll need to pass the `--lib` flag.

Comment: Doesn't `cargo doc` generate documentation for the *binary* by default? Because only after I added the `--lib` flag via `cargo doc --lib --open --document-private-items` I managed to generate docs for the library (including private items)

Comment: @l3utterfly that's why I added the doc comments to each crate ("THE LIBRARY" / "THE BINARY"). Then it's easy to see which one it opens by default. For me, it was the library. See also [For a package where a library and a binary have the same name, have cargo doc ignore the bin](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/4341#issuecomment-321667740).

Comment: Hmm.. I have different behaviour, my cargo docs the "binary" by default. Probably a config in my cargo.toml file. Thanks

Comment: @l3utterfly are you on Linux or Windows, by any chance? It may be something as silly as "order of files on disk".

Comment: I am on windows.